# Looking for a Metronome Program

Tags: windows, music

I am looking for a (simple) Program that will work as a metronome.

I have found some sites, but the change of rhythms don't work so well.

Are there any metronome software with

- Any time signature I want (like 4/4, 3/8, 7/4 etc)
- Any bpm
- Counting bars *with* strong beats on each bar

And won't need an internet access

I need it for Windows and possibly free.

Comment: You can download it. http://www.webmetronome.com/download. But I was saying have you tried the online version? Because you mentioned about finding some sites

Comment: Didn't know that! you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TempoPerfect Metronome](http://www.nch.com.au/metronome/):

- free
- change the BPM
- change the signature and subdivision
- Subdivide beats into accented beats and regular beats to emphasize different patterns
- Works on Windows 7, XP, Vista and 8 (+ Android and iPhone)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I found another good free metronome:

[**Open Metronome**](http://openmetronome.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

**Features**

- User definable BPM;
- Measure can be set to any length, with emphasis on any beat(s);
- Each beat can be one or more of over forty voices, with the supplied Samples covering the complete General MIDI percussion set, or custom samples;
- Visual indicator as well as audible output;
- Windows Mobile metronome keeps itself alive during suspend-states (the screen can still be turned off);
- "Hotkeys" can be assigned to various functions, such as increase/ decrease tempo;
- The maximum and minimum tempo available via the tempo slider can be set;
- Settings are automatically saved, and can be exported for use on another machine;
- Audio output can be saved as a WAV file for playback on another device (e.g., non-Windows mobile device);
- Support for "Playing in Fix" (Control of microtiming/ dialect);
- Extensive ToolTips.